# Custom class object in Initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have a class Bar:

```
class Bar
{
public:
Bar(void);
~Bar(void);
};
```

And a class `Foo` that gets a reference to `Bar` object as a constructor parameter and needs to save it in a private member `bar_` :

```
class Foo
{
private:

Bar& bar_;
public:
Foo(Bar& bar) : bar_(bar) {}
~Foo(void) {}
};
```

This doesn't compile :

> overloaded member function not found in 'Foo'
>
> missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Now i suspect couple of things that i need to assure, the second error is for `Bar& bar_;` declaration in `Foo`. Do i need to use an explicit constructor when declaring `bar_` ?

I am interested in learning how the compiler works regarding this matter, so a detailed explanation would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT

Okay I am posting a new code, since apparently there was nothing wrong with my code.
`Parser.h`:

```
#pragma once
class Parser
{
private:
std::istream& inputStream_;
Analyzer& analyzer_;
public:
Parser(std::istream &inputStream, Analyzer& analyzer);
~Parser(void);
};
```

`Parser.cpp` :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Analyzer.h"
Parser::Parser(std::istream &inputStream, Analyzer& analyzer ) : inputStream_(inputStream),     analyzer_(analyzer) {}

Parser::~Parser(void) {}
```

`Analyzer.h` :

```
 #pragma once
class Analyzer
{
public:
    Analyzer(void);
    ~Analyzer(void);
};
```

Comment: The code is fine (apart from missing definitions of Bar's c-tor and d-tor), your error message mentions `Parser` - what is it?

Comment: This compiles - http://ideone.com/caFF2

Comment: above your class Foo, have you declared Bar/included bar.h or do you have a forward declaration i.e. class Bar; ?

Comment: sorry, i've made some changes to my code to illustrate the problem and omitted details that are irrelevant , why downvote for a mistake ?

Comment: They are relevant. The downvote is because you didn't check your question before posting it.

Comment: You will need to have declaration of the `Bar` class for the `Foo` ctor to work. Add a header include for `Bar`. If you move your member definitions out of `Foo.h` to `Foo.cpp` you will need to forward declare `Bar` in `Foo.h` and then add a header include (`#include "Bar.h"`) in `Foo.cpp`. Of course, if `Foo` is a class template, you have to stick it in the header file if your compiler does not support `extern`-ed templates.

Comment: @Michael: I am sure Luchian makes mistakes as much as the next guy, that is not a problem. But not checking your question before posting it wastes the time of those trying to help you. They are right in downvoting you for the annoyance.

Comment: @Michael If it was just a small mistake, correct it (as you already did) and see if the down-vote vanishes. When seeing a bad question one does not neccessarily know that its badness is just due to small error, it could just be a bad question, for which down-voting is the best idea to emphasize its badness. And well, rechecking a question is really mandatory.

Comment: Well, not downvoting you: downvoting the question, which is entirely different.

Comment: @ChristianRau the question was changed, but it still is a bad one. The code compiles. So it's not tested.

Comment: i've posted the original code instead of the simplified version

Comment: @Michael - and then we see that you should add an `#include "Analyzer.h"` to the Parser.h file.

Comment: @BoPersson *sigh* i'm alwasy confused if i should put the includes in the cpp file or the headers file. Thank you. i am voting to close this question since i don't think there is need for another include mistake in SO. just don't understand why the compiler throws such bad error descriptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't compile :
>
> ```
> overloaded member function not found in 'Foo'    
> missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> ```

The code snippet you provided does indeed compile. I can tell you a little bit about these errors though.

The first error message happens when you compile a method that has the same name but a different signature from methods declared with the same name in your class.  For example, if you had:

```
class A {
public:
    int foo (int);
};

int A::foo () { return 0; }
```

The compiler will issue an error about not finding an overloaded member function. The compiler thinks `foo` is overloaded, because `foo(void)` is different from `foo(int)`.

The second error happens when you define a variable or function without a type. This is usually not the actual problem, but a consequence of some other problem. For example, if your code tried to use a class before it was declared, like:

```
B b;
class B {};
```

You would get the second error about missing type specifier, but it is talking about `B` on the first line.